# How to modify google maps code to use sql rather than hard coded xml

Tags: mysql, xml, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have 2 google map scripts (both for api V3).

One is designed to use data from an xml file which is hard coded.
The  other is designed to use a 'php' script to create an xml file by drawing the data from a sql database each time the map is loaded.

I want to use the first script (it has other map features compared to the second), but want to draw the data from my sql database.

When I modify the script in first file to do this it does not work (ie no markers are loaded in the map).

here is the xml file code

```
downloadUrl("categories.xml", function(doc) {
var xml = xmlParse(doc);
var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
var detail = markers[i].getAttribute("detail");
```

here is the code used with a mysql database

```
  downloadUrl("genxml.php", function(data) {
  var xml = parseXml(data);
  var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
  var detail = markers[i].getAttribute("detail");
```

So I am not sure why using the code from the second script in the first is now working.

Is there anyone familiar enough with the google api and using mySql to be able to advise.

Thanks.

Comment: What's parseXml and xmlParse? Does it matter that they are different?

Comment: I am not sure what the differences are - but they both work in the scripts they are from.

Comment: I don't think there's enough information for us to help you. Does genxml.php produce exactly the same thing as categories.xml? I would try loading genxml.php in a browser to make sure

Comment: The file genxml.php returns the same field data as categories.xml (plus some more). The two maps can be seen here [link](http://ukf.com/sqlmaps/category/categories.html) and here [link](http://ukf.com/sqlmaps/category/categories1.html). The first is the mySql version, the second is the xml.

Comment: My console says parseXml is not defined. Use xmlParse on categories.html and hopefully it should work.

Comment: Thanks Lil, that did the trick - much appreciated. I have limited coding experience and it never crossed my mind to check why the original 'sql' script did not have an accompanying js file and the categories one did. The original used and defined parsexml in the the body of the actual script.

Comment: @Lilina Why don't you transfer your answer from the comments into a question, so that it may be accepted? It helps everyone. I just came in and had to read all the way to the end to understand that this question is already answered. No big deal, but it will help others to know that you found an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed one script says `xmlParse`, and the other, `parseXml`. Most likely this inconsistency is the cause of unexpected behavior. It is useful to keep a JavaScript console open, such as Firebug for Firefox or Google Chrome's developer tools (press F12 or Ctrl+Shift+I).